# Is RPC itself a network protocol?

Tags: rest, protocol, rpc

*Design Data Intensive Applications* compares RPC and REST. It [says](https://books.google.com/books?id=p1heDgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&lpg=PT166&dq=The%20RPC%20model%20tries%20to%20make%20a%20request%20to%20a%20remote%20network%20service%20look&pg=PT166#v=onepage&q=The%20RPC%20model%20tries%20to%20make%20a%20request%20to%20a%20remote%20network%20service%20look&f=false)

> The RPC model tries to make a request to a remote network service look the same as calling a function or method in your programming language,  within  the  same  process  (this  abstraction  is  called  location  transparency).

[and](https://books.google.com/books?id=p1heDgAAQBAJ&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&ppis=_e&lpg=PT166&dq=The%20RPC%20model%20tries%20to%20make%20a%20request%20to%20a%20remote%20network%20service%20look&pg=PT168#v=onepage&q=Part%20of%20the%20appeal%20of%20REST%20is%20that%20it%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20try%20to%20hide%20the%20fact%20that%20it%E2%80%99s%20a%20network%20protocol.&f=false)

> Part of the appeal of REST is that it doesn’t try to hide the fact
>   that it’s a network protocol.

Does REST being a network protocol  mean that it is itself HTTP protocol?

Is RPC itself a network protocol?

Thanks.

Comment: A protocol implies state(s) and perhaps a state machine.  RPC is pretty high level; the state in RPC is call (passing parameters) and return (passing return value): request & response -- pretty simple, but arguably a degenerate protocol, I guess.  Still, a real protocol usually includes more, such as establishing (and closing) connections, handling errors (i.e. connection & transmission errors, e.g. via re-transmissions; program faults & exceptions), timeouts, and maybe security as well.

Comment: Also, it's worth pointing out that REST is not a network protocol.

Answer (score 4):

> Does REST being a network protocol  mean that it is itself HTTP protocol?

ReST is not a network protocol. ReST is an *Architectural Style*. The fact that ReST is an *Architectural Style* and not a protocol is *so* important that Roy Fielding's PhD Thesis which introduces ReST is even titled [*Architectural Styles and
the Design of Network-based Software Architectures*](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/top.htm):

> An *architectural style* is a coordinated set of architectural constraints that restricts the roles/features of architectural elements and the allowed relationships among those elements within any architecture that conforms to that style.

Also, ReST being an Architectural Style means that it is not the same as HTTP. The only relationship that ReST has to HTTP is that Roy Fielding, the author of the ReST Thesis, is also one of the main designers of HTTP/1.0, HTTP/1.1, HTTP/2, and HTTP/3.

The ReST Architectural Style is based on the Architectural Style of the World Wide Web, and HTTP was designed to be a good protocol for implementing ReSTful Architectures, but other than that, they are completely orthogonal.

XML-RPC and SOAP can use HTTP as a Transport layer, but they are most definitely not ReSTful. Likewise, you can implement ReSTful Architectures on top of protocols other than HTTP.

> Is RPC itself a network protocol?

No, RPC is not a protocol. RPC is a broad term that means pretty much exactly what it says: **C**alling **P**rocedures that are on the **R**emote end.

There are many RPC protocols, some of the more well-known ones are ONC RPC (formerly Sun RPC) which forms the basis of NFS, and DCE/RPC which forms the basis of MSRPC which in turn is the basis for DCOM and CIFS/SMB. There's also XML-RPC, SOAP, JSON-RPC, JSON-WSP, Ernie, and many others.

In Object-Oriented Systems, there is the very closely related concept of *Remote Method Invocation* with implementations such as CORBA, Java-RMI, Microsoft .NET Remoting, RPyC, Distributed Ruby, and many others.

The general idea behind the statement in the book is valid, however, even if the author mixes up the definition of what a "network protocol" is.

Remote communication over the Network has some failure modes and behaviors that are fundamentally incompatible with what we normally expect from a Procedure Call. For example, we do not expect a procedure call to fail. The procedure *itself* can obviously fail, throw an exception, run into an infinite loop, etc. but the *call* will always succeed. This is of course not guaranteed over the network. The call instruction could get sent but then get lost on the network.

This means that the idea of *location-transparency*, where you make every call look like a local call, is flawed.

The other way round, however, works much better: make every call look like a *remote* call. This is essentially the basis of environments that are based on *Asynchronous Messaging*, such as Actor Systems and Erlang, for example.

Comment: 'the call will always succeed' - almost: a stack overflow isn't the procedure failing, but the mechanism implementing the call hitting a protection boundary of some kind.

Answer (score 3):

No.

RPC is a loose, broad concept, which ultimately boils down to "performing functions somewhere else".

There are a variety of RPC implementations that have their own protocols, of varying specificity. Some protocols, like JSON-RPC, are flexible to the transport layer, others specify specific, binary network protocols. Others, expect to be run over HTTP. Like many things in the programing world, there are abstraction layers piled on top of each other. Some are built upon another RPC service below it.

REST, as most implementations go, is a common style of implementing an RPC interface. That claim I just made there is contentious, and there are many REST advocates that will insist it's not RPC, but ultimately what makes REST different than others are mostly non-fundamental details. REST is specifically run over the HTTP protocol, but it itself is less of a protocol but an architectural style.

I wouldn't call it a protocol because there is a lot of leeway in the implementation of some of the details of the interface, such as how request bodies are formed, whether information is in query parameters vs request body, layout of request URIs, and stuff like that. As a result, many call their interfaces RESTful to indicate it adheres to the general style rather than a specific, standard definition. Some tools, such as Swagger, exist to try to create that standard definition and way of doing things, and is an example of a layered RPC.

Answer (score 1):

The term RPC is ambiguous. It’s an abstract programming concept, and at the same time, it’s a family of network protocols that define the messages to be exchanged to implement this concept.

This ambiguity and the existence of several protocol standards may lead you to find contradicting answers.

Depending on the context, RPC can mean very specific network protocols:

- the low level [ONC RPC protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5531)  standardized by IETF in RFC 5531. It works on top of the TCP transport layer.
- higher level protocols such as [XML-RPC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC) or [JSON RPC](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC) on the top of any other network protocol suitable for transport (e.g. http)

The RPC protocols belong to the application layer of the TCP/IP model (i.e. anything above TCP). In the [OSI model](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_network_protocols_(OSI_model)) they belong to th session layer.

But if you mention RPC together with REST, it’s probably more about the conceptual design rather than the protocol.